# make groups of radio buttons for an array of questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a feedback_answers variable that has multiple questions.
For each question, I need to create a group of radio buttons and one checkbox.
So i wrote this in the main rhtml:

```
<% form_for @feedback_answers do|answers_form| %>
    <% @feedback_answers.each do |q| %>
            <tr class="answerRow">
                <td><%= q.question.body %></td>
                <td><%= render :partial => "radios_with_cb", :locals => {:feedback_answer => q} %></td>
            </tr>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And then in the partial I have this:

```
<% fields_for :feedback_answer do |f| %>
        <%= f.radio_button :answer_grade, 1 %> 1 
        <%= f.radio_button :answer_grade, 2 %> 2 
        <%= f.radio_button :answer_grade, 3 %> 3 
        <%= f.radio_button :answer_grade, 4 %> 4 
        <%= f.radio_button :answer_grade, 5 %> 5 
        <%= f.check_box :answer_grade %> <%= l(:cb_unrelated) %>
<% end %>
```

But I get errors. Can someone help?

Comment: What `errors` you got? Please post those `errors`.

Comment: undefined method `feedback_answer_feedback_answer_feedback_answer_feedback_answer_feedback_answer_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x5184fd8>

Comment: update `<% @feedback_answers.each do |q| %>` to `<% answers_form.each do |q| %>`

Comment: Post your full error stack

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues:

1. A `form_for` should wrap a single object, not multiple objects as you seem to have done with `form_for @feedback_answers`.
2. You must use an output ERB block if you want your form to show up in the page, so `<%= form_for ...` instead of `<% form_for ...`.
3. Within the `form_for` you should use the form generator object (in your case it's called `answer_form`) for object interactions. So instead of `<% @feedback_answers.each do |q| %>` I would expect something more like `<% answer_form.feedback_answers.each do |q| %>`
4. When rendering a partial that renders a portion of your form you need to pass the form generator along with it so the fields in the partial can render fields on the same form. So you should do e.g. `<%= render :partial => "radios_with_cb", :locals => {:answers_form => answers_form, :feedback_answer => q} %>`.
5. Inside of the partial: A `fields_for` statement should be called on a form generator object, so you want: `<%= answers_form.fields_for :feedback_answer do |f| %>`
6. Again, you will need to use an ERB output block if you want the `fields_for` to show up in the page, so `<%= answers_form.fields_for ...`

See also the [Rails Guide on Binding a From to an Object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object).